# Chrome 80 how to decode cookies python To powershell

Tags: python, powershell, encryption

```
import os
import json
import base64 
import win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

path = r'%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State'
path = os.path.expandvars(path)
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    encrypted_key = json.loads(file.read())['os_crypt']['encrypted_key']
encrypted_key = base64.b64decode(encrypted_key)                                       # Base64 decoding
encrypted_key = encrypted_key[5:]                                                     # Remove DPAPI
decrypted_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(encrypted_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]  # Decrypt key

data = bytes.fromhex('763130...') # the encrypted cookie
nonce = data[3:3+12]
ciphertext = data[3+12:-16]
tag = data[-16:]

cipher = AES.new(decrypted_key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
plaintext = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag) # the decrypted cookie
```

This code works so great , But I need this code with powershell , I have trouble with decoding

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Security
$ExtensionFile = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"
$jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path $ExtensionFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$enckey = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($jsondata.os_crypt.encrypted_key)).Substring(5)
$deckey = [Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($enckey, $null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] incl. error message(s).

Answer (score 1):

The Unprotect method is expecting a byte array for the first parameter, you are feeding it a string.

```
public static byte[] Unprotect (byte[] encryptedData, byte[] optionalEntropy, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope scope);
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Working solution:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Security
$ExtensionFile = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"
$jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path $ExtensionFile | ConvertFrom-Json

#convert your key from base64 to a char array
$encKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($jsondata.os_crypt.encrypted_key.ToString());

#remove the first 5 elements from the key array
$encKey= $encKey[5..$encKey.Length];

$decKey=[System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($encKey,$null, [System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser);
```

If this was of any help to you, please mark my answer as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently. Firstly you should decrypt the key using DPAPI and then decrypt the cookie using AES-GCM.

Thanks for the python solution - I have used it as a reference.
That's my PowerShell solution

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Security
$ExtensionFile = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data\Local State"
$protectedDataPath = "$($env:HOMEPATH)\Downloads\enc.cookie.bin"
$jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path $ExtensionFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$encKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($jsondata.os_crypt.encrypted_key.ToString());
$encKey= $encKey[5..$encKey.Length];
 
$decryptedKey = [Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData]::Unprotect($enckey,$null, [Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope]::CurrentUser)
 
$encodedCookieData=[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($protectedDataPath)
 
[byte[]]$nonce = $encodedCookieData[3..14]
[byte[]]$ciphertext = $encodedCookieData[15..($encodedCookieData.Length-1-16)]
[byte[]]$tag = $encodedCookieData[($encodedCookieData.Length-16)..($encodedCookieData.Length-1)]
Write-Host "nonce:  [$(($nonce|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')]"
Write-Host "tag:    [$(($tag|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')]"
Write-Host "decryptedKey:   [$(($decryptedKey|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')]"
Write-Host "ciphertext: [$(($ciphertext|ForEach-Object ToString X2) -join '')]"
 
 
[byte[]]$plainText=new-object byte[] $ciphertext.Length
[System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm] $oAESGcm = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesGcm (,$decryptedKey)
$oAESGcm.Decrypt($nonce, $ciphertext, $tag, $plainText, $null)
Write-Host "plainText:  [$([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($plainText))]"
```

Tested on a Chrome Canary v98 / Windows 10.